# JsonConvert.SeralizeObject drops boolean properties if false

Tags: c#, serialization, json.net

I have an object:

```
public class Feature
{
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public bool Value { get; set; }
}
```

And I have another object which has a property as `IEnumerable<Feature>` like this:

```
public class SomeObject 
{
    public IEnumerable<Feature> Features { get; set; }
    // ..other props
}
```

I have an instance of my object:

```
var someObject = new SomeObject { 
    Features = new List<Feature> { 
        new Feature { Code = "foo", Value = true },
        new Feature { Code = "bar", Value = false }
    }
}
```

and when I do a `Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(someObject);` it drops the value that's false e.g. :

```
{\"features\":[{\"code\":\"foo\",\"value\":true},{\"code\":\"bar\"}]}
```

I don't want that, I want this:

```
{\"features\":[{\"code\":\"foo\",\"value\":true},{\"code\":\"bar\",\"value\":false}]}
```

How can I do that? Do I need to add some attribute to my `Feature` object? or perhaps I need to use a different Serializer?

**Update** In response to @Zorkind for more information.

I retrieve a `BsonDocument` from Mongo and do a

```
MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.BsonSerializer.Deserialize<SomeObject>(resultFromMongo)
```

That bit seems to work, I get my object with 2 Features in, both contain a Code and a Value even the one where Value is set to false;[image]

Then I take this and add to an api response:

```
var risk = _store.Load(request.Id);
if (risk != null)
{
    context.Response.ContentType = ContentType.Json;
    await context.Response.WriteAsync(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(risk));
    return;
}
```

So `risk` in the code above is my `SomeObject` instance in my examples earlier.

Now if I break after the risk has been loaded and do a `JsonConvert.SerializeObject(risk)` in my immediate window, I get the serailized version without the false value (so even before I add it to the response)

Comment: how are you serializing? you converting or responding in some API call?

Comment: There is more you ain't telling, because this code works well. (For the exception you forgot to add `JsonConvert.` before SerializeObject.)

Comment: The code you've shown works as you want it to in a completely vanilla project. I'm using Newtonsoft.Json v10.0.3

Comment: Your code works for me perfectly.

Comment: @OrelEraki So I did, thanks.

Comment: Ok, that's interesting. I've just trimmed the bits out of a larger project for this question. I can't see anything obvious that should affect this but I will do some more digging

Comment: @Zorkind I've added more info to the question

Comment: Thanks @Zorkind adding that attribute does indeed fix it :) Something must be overriding the default JsonSerializerSettings in my app to ignore defaults I guess.

Comment: @Rodders agreed, i thought that too. :-)